# How to combine several models in one forms in django?

Tags: django, python-3.x

I am having 4 models in Django: Products, Orders,lines_Orders, and Invoice. Based on these models, I would like to create a form that will generate the invoice given an order number. But I don't know how the views could be and how to combine these models into one form.

```
class Product(models.Model):
    # productId=models.IntegerField(auto_created=True)
    customerId=models.ForeignKey(Customers, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    productNumber=models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True)
    productDescription=models.CharField(max_length=25)
    unitPrice = models.FloatField()
    storageQuantity=models.FloatField()

class Orders(models.Model):
    orderID=models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    customerID = models.ForeignKey(Customers, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    oderDate = models.DateTimeField()

class Order_lines(models.Model):
    oderID = models.ForeignKey(Orders, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    productNumber=models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity = models.FloatField(default=0.00)

class Invoice(models.Model):
    dateInvoice=models.DateField()
    receiveDate=models.DateField()
    OrderNumber=models.ForeignKey(Orders, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Please assist

Answer (score 0):

Refer to 
[Django Inline Formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/)